# Run F# on Visual Studio Code on OSX

Tags: macos, f#, mono, visual-studio-code

Any thoughts on how to run F# on Visual Studio Code on OSX?

I've tried generating a console app with yo aspnet, changed the Program.cs to Program.fs, obviously rewriting the it in F#, and it doesn't work when I try to build or run using dnu.

Comment: Try some sanity checking: See if your fsi (or also sometimes called fsharpi) works. See if fsc (aka fsharpc) works, compiling your program from command line. Do a small hello world .fsx file and see if it works in the interactive console... If all that works, at least you can be sure your mono and fsharp stuff is properly set up.

Comment: stupid question, but is the F# compiler called at all when you just replace the file? In the usual VS, they are different kinds of project files.

Comment: strange that it is a duplicate when this is the only one that shows up when searching for [vscode] [f#]